# How to handle complex object creation correctly, even if objects have similar constructors

Tags: design-patterns

What is the best design pattern or method for handling complex object creation? Should this pattern change if some objects will have the same constructor?

I have a factory pattern class that contains the required constants to generate the object required. When creating an object, the developer should pass in the constant of their choice. Some of these objects will simply a parent constructor but others might be more complex.

Would the builder design pattern be better here?

```
class IbmApiRequestTypeBuilder {

    const INSTRUMENT_REQUEST = array("id" => 0,
        "requestUrl" => "/instrument/requestInstrumentList",
        "requestType" => "post",
        "requestBodyHead"=>"RequestInstrumentList",
        "requestBody" => "requestInstrumentList");

    const CREATE_SESSION_REQUEST = array("id" =>1,
        "requestUrl" => "/instrument/requestSession",
        "requestType" => "post",
        "requestBodyHead"=>"requestSession",
        "requestBody"=>"sessionRequest");


    public static function createApiRequestType($type) {

        $requestObj = null;

        switch($type['id']) {
            case 0:
                $requestObj = new IbmApiRequestInstruments($type['requestUrl'],
                $type['requestType'],
                $type['requestBodyHead'],
                $type['requestBody']);
            break;
        case 1:
            $requestObj = new IbmApiRequestSession($type['requestUrl'],
                $type['requestType'],
                $type['requestBodyHead'],
                $type['requestBody']);
            break;
         }

        return $requestObj;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `type.id` is always the only criteria for how to create your request objects. I would say this *factory method* will work and I like it's simplicity.

On the other hand, if there are many configurations, many variants, I might choose a *builder pattern* that is more flexible.  In that case, the constant values could be used as defaults, that the builder can overwritten when used.

But if you keep this class as is, I would rename it to IbmApiRequestTypeFactory and rename the method to simply create($type). As it is not a builder and from the context it can only create one type of object.
I

Comment: I guess I was more worried about have the same snippet of code repeating (the $type[] array values being passed into the constructor). I guess I have a few ways of handling this. I could always pass the whole array rather than each value on it's own.

I could also do the separate logic for each object in the switch and then use a setter on the final statement afterwards to see the request details

Comment: You could do that, but that would tie these constructors more closely to your factory design.  But if the factory is the only users of them, that is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like a good candidate for `factory method` pattern, I think you only need just simplify it little bit, like:

```
public static function createApiRequestType($type) {
    $requestObj = null;
    $className = '';
    switch($type['id']) {
        case 0:
            $className = 'IbmApiRequestSession';
            break;
        case 1:
            $className = 'IbmApiRequestInstruments';
            break;
     }
    return new $className($type['requestUrl'],
        $type['requestType'],
        $type['requestBodyHead'],
        $type['requestBody']
    );
}
```